# Method Returning list of Strings from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have this program reads a file made up with words line by line into my Arraylist, then I want to print this ArrayList on to my console also line by line, however, I can only manage to print 1 word from that list (you can understand why from my code below).  I would appreciate all kinds of input.

*Note1: I have tested both my reader method and my ArrayList they seem to work well, I can see all the elements that are added into my ArrayList.

*Note2: I could just print out with print-stream however I can't change the method signature, thus I have to return String with this method and I could not find any way to print the whole list on to my console.

*Edit:  To clarify I do not want to print the list, I want this method to pass the String (as a list with all the elements) to another class's method that puts this String I returned from this method on to text box I created with GUI. Therefore I need this method to "return String(arStr)" somehow but I could not figure out yet.

```java
public static String toStringFromArrayList(ArrayList<String> arStr) {
    String result = null;
    for (String s : arStr) {
        result = s;

    }
    return result;
}
```

** This is what I meant to do if anyone needs a similar solution can check it below **

```
public static String toStringFromArrayList (ArrayList<String> arStr) {

    String result ="";



     for (String s: arStr) {



      result += s+"\n";



     }

return result;
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips on debugging your code. This will help you understand what your code is doing.

Comment: You do not need `toString()` for a `String`.

Comment: To just print the whole list, you can do `System.out.println(arStr);`. This will print the entire list on one line, though.

Comment: *You* have to define the logic, how the list of multiple strings shall become a single string. Is `return arStr.toString();` the right thing? Or rather `return String.join("\n", arStr);`? We can't know what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning each element to `result` in te loop. Then you return the last assignment, hence you only print out one word

For example: Say you have the words "this, that, so, and she" in `arStr` then `she` will be the last word assigned to the 'result' which you then return.

Also, if you want to assign `null` to result then you shoud omit the `""` around null, because now you are assigning the String value `"null"` to the variable results instead of a null value

Edit: One last tip, if you are using `Java 8` or higher you can also use the `forEach()` method of the arraylist to print each string value. This is how you would do it.

`arStr.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));`

If you use this you don't need the method you've made anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I 've found that method however as my method signature requires me to return String, I cant use the method you suggested as that method returns void. When I try to implement that I get an error stating "This method must return a result of type String"  Maybe just me being a rookie.

Comment: @Gwaithim you don't need your method anymore, you can use `forEach` in its place, all you have to do is print the words in the list no? So use `forEach` at the place where you are no calling your own method and delete your own method

Comment: also it is good practice to use the superclass `List<String>` as the argument datatype, instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: I have another class expecting String from that method, I am working on GUI , that method returning string to my another class that builds an interface with a text-box then I sort them etc. Thus I need to keep the method itself with the method signature.

Answer (score 2):

You are only returning the last String and aren't printing anything.
This prints every element of the the ArrayList n ints own line

```
public static void toStringFromArrayList (ArrayList arStr) {
    for (String s: arStr) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem, let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I could use that, however, my method requires me to have a return String statement, otherwise, I get an error saying "This method must return a result of type String"

Comment: @Gwaithim No problem. That is because your method is of type string. If you look at my code it is of type void so I don't need to return anything. Try replacing your existing method with mine and try again, let me know if it doesn't work or if you need further assistance :) - Ankit

Comment: Hey Ankit thanks for follow up. That method meant to return String so I couldnt change it but I found another way to return String line by line :)